# Image Upload with filefield Encoding to Base64 in ExtJs 4

Tags: javascript, php, extjs

How to upload image and convert the image into base64 string, here some code with listener on extjs :

```
xtype: 'filefield',
id: 'image',
emptyText: '-- Choose Image --',
fieldLabel: 'Photo',
name: 'image',
anchor: "82%",
buttonText: 'Browse',
buttonConfig: {
iconCls: ''
},
change: function() {
// this is get component
var valueElement = Ext.getCmp("component_image_upload").getValue();

// function upload image full path and encode to base64
// function here

// result to encode base64
var GenEncoded = valueElement;
Ext.getCmp("component_textarea").setValue( GenEncoded );
```

I try to add btoa function but it just convert the string on the filefield, not for uploading image :

```
// result to encode base64
var GenEncoded = btoa(valueElement);
Ext.getCmp("ttransdelivery_module_manualreceive_form_receive_ar_1_general_blk_i_form_text_2031").setValue( GenEncoded );
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use FileAPI for this. But keep in mind that it's not supported in all browsers. Check [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi) for support.

This should work:

```
change: function() {
     var valueElement = Ext.getCmp("component_image_upload").getValue();
     var reader = new FileReader();

     reader.onload = function(e) {
         Ext.getCmp("component_textarea").setValue(e.target.result);
     };
     reader.onerror = function(e) {
         //error reading file
     };  

     reader.readAsDataURL(valueElement.el);
}
```

Check the api of [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping, this is my listener code. This code work :

```
change: function() {
     var valueElement = Ext.getCmp('image').getEl().down('input[type=file]').dom.files[0];            
     var reader = new FileReader();

     reader.onload = function(e) {
          Ext.getCmp("ttransdelivery_module_manualreceive_form_receive_ar_1_general_blk_i_form_text_2031").setValue(e.target.result);
     };
     reader.onerror = function(e) {
          alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
     };  

     reader.readAsDataURL(valueElement);
}
```

Thanks for help mate